# Changing Attribute Type in Core Data with NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I have my Core Data Store and I use the flag 'NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption' so that whenever I make changes to the Core Data Model I first create a new model version, and the changes to the data models are automatically migrated.

However, I need to change an attribute type for one of my Entities. When I do this, the automatic migration doesn't seem to work and I get a Core Data error when I try to run my app.

Any way of setting this up to continue with the automatic model migration?

Comment: What "core data error" are you getting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attribute type change is not supported by the lightweight migration:

> For Core Data to be able to generate an inferred mapping model, changes must fit an obvious migration pattern, for example:
>
> - Simple addition of a new attribute
> - Removal of an attribute
> - A non-optional attribute becoming optional
> - An optional attribute becoming non-optional, and defining a default value
> - Renaming an entity or property

### Edit

I assume you're using the lightweight migration. But as Scott pointed out, maybe you aren't. If you want to use automatic migration (which is not the same as the lightweight migration), you can still do this by providing the mapping model. In this case:

> Core Data will attempt to locate the source and mapping models in the application bundles, and perform a migration.

But this migration will not be lightweight. Core Data will open two stores–the source and the target–and copy all entities in memory. So the memory consumed by the app depends on the amount of data in the store.

Comment: Though Wise Shepherd probably means lightweight migration, lightweight migration and automatic migration are not the same. With a mapping model, migration can still happen automatically (which is what `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` is for).

Comment: The options I'm passing when I load the store are: @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)};

Comment: In order to continue to use lightweight migration, can I increment the model version and just remove the atrribute in question, then increment the model version again and add an attribute with the same name but different type?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. Automatic migration (lightweight or not) doesn't support progressive migration. For example, you have models 1, 2, and 3. Your store file was generated with model 1. Now you run the app with the model 3. Automatic migration will try to find the mapping model from 1 to 3. If you specify NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, then the migration will try to infer the mapping model. But if in the model 3 the type of the attribute is different then in 1, the model can't be inferred.

Comment: It is possible to do the progressive migration, but you have to control the migration process manually.

Answer (score 16):

*You cannot use lightweight migration for this so it is a little bit harder (thanks Apple), but not impossible*

*step by step in Xcode 7.1:*

**1. Create the new model version:**

1. Select your `.xcdatamodeld` model -> `Editor` -> `Add model version ...`
2. Edit the new model's entity's `attribute type`
3. Change **current model version** to the new one *(File inspector). You should see the green tick mark moved.*

[image: Current model]

**2. Custom Core Data mapping model**

1. `New file -> Mapping Model` (Core Data -> Mapping Model)
2. Choose the `source` (from model) and `target` (to model) version of your model
3. The custom mapping model contains entities mappings called this way: `NameToName`. Change value expression of the changed attribute in target entity in this file reflect the one you need to: `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "<*transformingMethodName*>" , $source.<*attributeName*>)`

*- transformingMethodName: Your custom method that will be called to transform attribute type. (Will define it in the next step - hold on)*

*- attributeName: your changed attribute name*

5. Create `<*EntityName*>TransformationPolicy` class as a subclass of `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`
6. Implement `transformingMethodName` you defined above. *(Do what you need there to change the attribute type). Make sure you added this method to your header file as well*
7. **Register this class as custom entity migration policy** in the mapping model *(Model.xcmappingmodel -> File inspector -> third column -> Custom policy -> Enter the name of your TransformationPolicy class.)*

[image: Register migration policy class]

Comment: Any chance you could post an example of #3.  If I wanted to change foo, which was an Int in my first model, but want it to be a Double in my second model, what would the code look like to change foo from Int to Double?  Is there just 1 function in the class (EventTransformationPolicy) to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Hello, it is general guide. *transformingMethodName* is just a placeholder for the guide. You have to create your own method that will convert attribute types and refer to its name in #3.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář how can I manage this with multiple targets?