# Strange behaviour when inserting data into core-data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

**Edit 1**
While I understand that for this particular scenario (and other alike) I could use the mapping editor alone to migrate my store correctly so that the values in the persistent store don't jump around, but that's not a solution to my current problem but only avoids addressing the root of the problem. I am keen on sticking with my custom migration policy as this will give me a lot of control through the migration process, especially for future scenarious where setting up a custom migration policy will work for me. This is for a long term solution and not just for this scenario.

I urge you to try and help me solve the current situation at hand rather than diverting me to lightweight migration or advising me to avoid using a migration policy. Thank you.

I really do look forward to sorting this out and your valuable input/ideas on what I could do to fix this problem.

**What I have done:**
I have a migration policy set up so that the source data can be copied into the new destination data from `version 1` of the core model to `version 2`.

This is the migration policy:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error {

    // Create the product managed object
    Product *newProductInstance = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[mapping destinationEntityName]
                                                                inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];

    NSString *productCode = [sInstance valueForKey:@"productCode"];
    NSNumber *productPrice = [sInstance valueForKey:@"productPrice"];
    [newProductInstance setProductCode: productCode];
    [newProductInstance setProductPrice:productPrice];

    /**
     The previous old product entries didnt have anything for the last attribute,
     where as the new instances of product entity should have a default value of YES.
     */
    [newProductInstance setProductPriceNeedsUpdating:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    /*
    A test statement to make sure the destination object contains the correct
    values int he right properties:

    Product description: <NSManagedObject: 0xb983780> (entity: Product; id: 0xb9837b0 <x-coredata:///Product/t97685A9D-09B4-475F-BDE3-BC9176454AEF6> ; data: {
        productCode = 9999;
        productPrice = "2.09";
        productPriceNeedsUpdating = 1;
    })
    */
    NSLog(@"Product description: %@", [newProductInstance description]);

    // Set up the association between the old source product and the new destination Product for the migration manager
    [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance
             withDestinationInstance:newProductInstance
                    forEntityMapping:mapping];
    return YES;
}
```

So even though the tested properties show the correct values in runtime, the resultant values saved in the data model store is incorrect as seen in the snapshots.

**Here is a comparison from version 1 to version 2 of the data store.**

Version 1: Correct
[image]

to Version 2: Which is now storing the values incorrectly.

[image: Wrong values being saved into the database in the wrong fields]

The expected output should have the Product price inserted into the `productPrice` field and not in the `ProductPriceNeedsUpdating` field which should actually only have boolean values.
Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong, or explain whats happening here?

**UPDATE 1** - Here are my `entity mappings`:

[image: enter code here]

**Update 2 - 20/aug/2014 01:02 GMT**

When I remove the attribute `ProductPriceLastUpdated` of type `date` from version 1, and remove the attribute `ProductPriceNeedsUpdate` of type `boolean` in version 2, leaving only the two attributes that both match in version 1 and 2, then everything works. Even though I can leave it here and move on, I cant ignore the users that are currently using version 1 of the database which does have that pointless `ProductPriceLastUpdated` attribute which I need the type converted to boolean and also have the name changed to `ProductPriceNeedsUpdate`. Thats when things start going weird, and the price values are shown in the `ProductPriceNeedsUpdate` field instead of the `productPrice` field.

I hope someone can address the original problem and tell me why it is that the entityMapping, or more so, property mapping is not being saved properly?

**Update 3 - EntityMapping and properties:**

Version 1
[image]

Version 2
[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to do a lightweight migration? If you're simply adding a new field that's always set to YES by default, and removing another one, Core Data can handle it on its own, no need to do a custom migration.

Comment: @jcaron, I am building on this app, and will eventually require heavy migration, nothing is set to yes by default, that was just an exercise, I will continue increasing the fields, relationships, and may even branch out entities, split them into two, will eventually ... I can go on. The point is, I have custom heavy migration working like a charm, a progressive migration which can migrate from version 1 to version 6 by recursing a method that I have which continues to upgrade the store model until it matches the existing model. cont.

Comment: @jcaron, My question is about why the data is being inserted into a different field. Please try and avoid going off topic by discussing other forms of migration unless that has a direct relevant impact as to why my data is jumping around in between fields ;) :P

also, changing the attribute of fields is not something covered in lightweight migration. Have a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534859/changing-attribute-type-in-core-data-with-nsinfermappingmodelautomaticallyoption

Comment: @jcaron, thanks for taking the time to comment. Is there anything that you could think of that could probably be causing this problem?

Comment: Note quite sure the issue is in this part of the code. I supposed the commented output of the NSLog is the actual output? Have you checked http://cases.azoft.com/database-migration-ios-applications/ for clues?

Comment: Show your entity mapping.

Comment: @Mundi, Hi, thank you for having a look. Please have a look at the updated post where I have added a snapshots of my entityMappings.

Comment: The strange thing now is that When I reduce the attributes to only two, then the price works, but then the productCode becomes null then... its so strange! gosh its really frustrating.

Comment: I believe that there might be a problem with property mapping perhaps. Thats one of the possibilities that I have narrowed it down too. What do you guys think?

Comment: Hi @Pavan, I am looking into this.

Comment: @Mundi Thank you so much for just letting me know, its much appreciated - definitely gave some sort of relief there. Is there anyway we can enter a live discussion so that we can solve this problem once and for all - With the added benefit of you being able to see my screen? I've been racking my brains on this for the last 48 hours now, its becoming ridiculous, definitely need a second pair of eyes!

Comment: @Mundi, is there anything you'd like me to do that may help you in your cause? Screenshots, videos, anything?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario there is no need for a migration policy. You can just use the **mapping model** and do the following:

1. Map the non-changing entities to each other. In the mapping model editor it should say something like `A productCode              | $source.productCode`. This is already filled in for you.
2. The attribute to be dropped (`productPriceLastUpdated`) should not appear at all because when you created the mapping model you specified the source and destination models. As the destination model does not contain this attribute, it won't show up.
3. Where the new boolean attribute `productPriceNeedsUpdating` is shown, enter '1' for the "Value Expression" (this is equivalent to `@YES`). It should look like this:
   `A productPriceNeedsUpdating | 1`

Rather than define a policy, you can now just call

```
migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:
destinationType:destinationOptions:error
```

You can do very complex operations by just using the mapping model editor.

Your screen shots are from the *model editor*. Make sure you get familiar with the *mapping editor*.

Comment: Hi thanks for posting. I have a question, is there any reason why the result cannot be achieved with the custom migration policy? I'd like to resolve the matter with the current setup otherwise the problem at hand isn't being addressed but merely skipped. Can we please figure out why the problem I'm having is occuring? I'm happy to rework on the custom migration policy.

Comment: Remember that this is just a trivial scenario I have setup for much bigger things later on, eventually there will be a scenario and many more where custom migration policies would be more appropriate for myself. I'm looking for a long term solution instead of a solution that will only be suitable for 'this scenario' and similar to it.

Comment: I quickly wrote a sample project including the custom migration and it is working fine. I would recommend you step through the policy code line by line and see if everything has the values you expect. Your mapping model looks fine, but lacks the value `1` for the boolean. Make sure you completely delete the app from the simulator, set the previous version, run it, create some data, kill it, switch to the migration version and then step through the code.

Comment: Does it help to know that the subclass of Product changes through each revision, and that the latest revision for version 3 is different for version 2?

But I don't think that the subclass of Product (which matches the attributes to version 3) has anything to do with this.

Comment: It might. My version does not use any managed object subclasses. You are not mixing subclass best practices (setProperty) with managed object KVC (setValue:forKey:).

Comment: I remember seeing another question where you were advising something similar to another person who wanted to ensure data was persisted. Deleting the app would delete the data, the point of this is to make sure that the data persists `correctly` when I upgrade the store. As you can see from the migration policy in the original post of mine, line by line "it looks right" as well as the description of the `NSManagedObject` that I set the destination source to, and this does output the correct values as I have stated in the comments in the migrationPolicy code section. check it out

Comment: What do you mean by: `You are not mixing subclass best practices (setProperty) with managed object KVC (setValue:forKey:)`? I am only setting the property via `setProperty` in the migration policy. I'm using managed subclasses for other areas of my program where data would be saved into the store, using the `setProperty` helps in those areas of the program. I was also going to use 'setProperty` in the migration policy which I originally did, but then for simplicity's sake I oped for setValueForKey approach, atleast until the values were being transferred across between versions properly.

Comment: And finally 3) Would you care to share this sample migration policy project of yours so that I can have a look and compare? If you dont mind the trouble of uploading to your preferred site and then sharing the link. Thank you Mundi.

Comment: I would love to. But it is in swift... I hope you don't mind?

Comment: Aha, damn it! I haven't quite jumped on the bandwagon JUST yet, *embarrassed-face*. Is there a possibility of having it converted into objective-c... I hope you don't mind?

Comment: Sorry. You can still look at it at https://bitbucket.org/mundstein/migrationtest/. It is very readable and uses the same APIs, so you will find it is still quite instructive.

Comment: awesome ill have a look.

Comment: could you please check the two comments before that I had written before the comment I wrote about sharing the sample project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59676/discussion-between-pavan-and-mundi).