# change attribute type in entity and migrate the coredata

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I need to change my CoreData attribute type from one type to another and generate the NSManagedObject subclasss manually.
how to migrate the older version data to new one [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiU4d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZEkU.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534859/changing-attribute-type-in-core-data-with-nsinfermappingmodelautomaticallyoption ? But if you generate manually the code files, you can change the type manually in the code file.

Comment: I knew I can change it manually but for every time I change need to generate and delete the older class, is there anyother possible way for achieve this using CoreData migration

Comment: No, CoreData migration can't change your code at runtime. Why do you need to generate the class?  Why don't you autogenerate the extensions with the properties?

Comment: how to autogenerate the extension with the properties???

Comment: Use the Codegen setting in the data model. See [Generating Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/generating_code?language=objc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I need to change the attribute type this come under the heavyweight
migration. so I need to add new version for my coredata.

**1.create new model version**

follow only for creating new model version

[Changing Attribute Type in Core Data with NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534859/changing-attribute-type-in-core-data-with-nsinfermappingmodelautomaticallyoption)

**2.core datamapping model**

i) `new file->mapping model` (Core Data -> Mapping Model)

ii) Choose the source `(from model)` and target `(to model)` version of your model

iii) Create `class(any name)` as a subclass of `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`

iv) override a method called `createDestinationInstances`. Below is my override method which transfer id from string to int

```
override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {
    
    
    let destMOC = manager.destinationContext
    guard let destinationEntity = mapping.destinationEntityName else{
        fatalError("Destination Entity name error")
    }
    print(destinationEntity)
    
    guard let sId = sInstance.value(forKey: "id") as? String,
          let name = sInstance.value(forKey: "name"),
          let dId = Int(sId)
    else{
        fatalError("source object didnt have valube id")
    }
    
    let context = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Entity", into: destMOC)
   
    context.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    context.setValue(dId, forKey: "id")
}
```

v) Register this class as custom entity migration policy in the mapping model `(Model.xcmappingmodel -> File inspector -> third column -> Custom policy`  put class name as `Module.className`

**(eg for registering class)**
[image]

**(eg for module and className)**

[[image][[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1okxl.png)

that's it. if you run it will migrate to new version.